# В чем разница между evdev и xinput?

Tags: linux, мышь

Я раньше использовал MX-21.3 “Wildflower” там когда пишешь "xinput --list-props "Logitech USB Optical Mouse"" была такая строчка "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" и я мог его регулировать и подбирать оптимальную скорость мыши. Но в MX-23 “Libretto” beta 2. Такой строчки уже нет. И мне крайне не нравится поведение мыши в данной системе. А пользоваться постоянно старой версией как то не хочется. И я заметил что в большинстве дистрибутивов отсутствует "Device Accel Constant Deceleration". Если я зохочу пользоваться новым дистрибутивом я хотел бы что бы там была эта опция. Что это? и как это вернуть?.

Comment: [Mouse acceleration](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Mouse_acceleration)